# How to plot heatmap incrementally?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, heatmap

I want to plot a heatmap with a size of 30 million points by X-axis and 10 points by Y-axis. 
Data will come incrementally with smaller portions like (30000, 10).

How can I incrementally plot `heatmap` (maybe with `imshow` or another function) to optimize memory? Because there is no opportunity to collect all data.

I don't need any animation.

Comment: do you want separate plots for each 30,000 chunk? how many pixels wide is your computer monitor?

Comment: @PaulH I want to get a single picture, but I don't need a great resolution. some `figsize=(20, 10)` is enough

Comment: OK, I guess I'm just curious how your going to look at a 30 million pixels on a monitor that is in all likelihood <<10,000 pixels wide

Comment: if the data is going to be all on the same figure, the data all have to be in memory in some form

Comment: i don't follow what you're saying.

Comment: @PaulH If size was (300, 10) coming with chunks by (30, 10) How can I plot heatmap step-by-step without collecting all points?

Comment: you can't. if you're showing all of the data on one figure, all of the data will be collected on that figure